# My SQL select query code not work properly in C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, debugging, webforms

I am new to ASP.net. Try to search the specific row on the base of Primary key which is my `StudentInfo`. I have try many queries but give me `null` result when I debug. All other queries like insert, update, Delete work fine except select queries.

This is Search Button code:

```
protected void Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
      String query = "select * from StudentInfo where StudentId=" + int.Parse(Id.Text);
            
            DataTable dt = db.Search(query);
            GridView1.DataSourceID = null;
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```

This is search function code which I written into class:

```
public DataTable Search(String query)
        {
            DataTable dt = null;
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                dt = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(dt);
                return dt;
            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                return dt;
            }
```

I want when I click on search button the matching Id result will show in GridView. But it show nothing although data is present in data base. When I debug it give me null in dataTable:

Can see here after query passing to function result is Null in debuging:
[image]

**Same problem in select all data from data base.**

I also create a view all record button and want when I click on it all record will show in GridView. But when I click on it give me Null same like upper search result.

This is View all record buttton code:

```
protected void ViewAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String query = "select * from StudentInfo";
            DataTable dt = db.Search(query);
            //GridView1.DataSourceID = null;
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();

        }
```

In this I also pass query to search function which code is mention above.

This DataTable result is also same as search query which is null even records is exist in data base.

So what is the mistake which I make??

**This is complete code of Dbconn class:**

```
namespace CRUD_Operatins
{
    public class DbConn
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        public bool UDI(String query)
        {
            try {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                int c = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (c > 0)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
        public DataTable Search(String query)
        {
           // DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataTable dt = null;
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                dt = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(dt);
                return dt;
            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                return dt;
            }
      
        }

}
}
```

**This is form.aspx code:**

```
public partial class StudentInfo : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        DbConn db = new DbConn();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           String query = "select * from StudentInfo where StudentId=" + int.Parse(Id.Text);

            DataTable dt = db.Search(query);
            GridView1.DataSourceID = null;
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

        protected void ViewAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String query = "select * from StudentInfo";
            DataTable dt = db.Search(query);
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code is open to [SQL injection attacks](https://bobby-tables.com/). You should use parameterized queries instead.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the `catch` clause of the `Search` method. There's likely an exception thrown, in which case `Search` will return the initial `null` value for `DataTable`. If you inspect the thrown exception in the debugger, you will likely find the reason why this fails.

Comment: @Steven Not go to catch method return in try block

Comment: You have to post the full code for your db class. Is that class static, or did/do you create a instance some place on the current web page to persist that db class? Seems to me, the db class is going out of scope. Each button click or use of that db class will require you to create a new instance of that class, unless you make the class and its methods static.

Comment: @Albert D. Kallal Now you can see the full code of Db class I have edited the post

Comment: And thus now in your code, where did you create an instance of that class? Do you create an instance in onload? I only ask since perhaps the class has gone out of scope?

Comment: @Albert D. Kallal Now you can see the  `from.apsx` code Where I create the instance of Dbconn class

Answer (score 0):

Check what value is coming in query variable via debugging the code. Also check whether any data exists in the table for your query

Comment: Same value is coming which I entre in field. And yes data exist in the table.
When test same query in testing option of visual studio then give me result. But here in code not working

Comment: You were not filling datatable with any content in the search method,First you need to load the datatable with the query results

Comment: I Think I do that. Because after adapter I Fill it

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
try
{
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    dt = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(dt);
    return dt;
}
catch (SqlException e)
{
    return dt;
}
```

You must need to create a `DataTable` Object, which is:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
```

Comment: Still Same issue.